# Converting a foreach into contains forall matcher

Tags: scala, specs2

I have the following expression in a spec, with the intention of ensuring that each element has a value `distanceToEnd` that is very close to the sum of the `distanceFromPrevious` values of the elements following it.

```
foo.tails.foreach {
  case h +: t => h.distanceToEnd.miles must
    beCloseTo(t.map(_.distanceFromPrevious.miles).sum, 10e-10)
  case _ => ok
}
```

Ideally, this should be in the form `foo.tails must contain { ... }.forall`, but I have trouble understanding how to create the necessary `ValueCheck` parameter for `contains`. How would I convert this particular example?

Comment: What part of this is side-effecting?

Comment: Not essential to the question. The entire expression resolves to `Unit`. Though the spec behaves OK.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand your goal here. It seems unusual because the argument of `forall` is typically pure.

Comment: My goal is the logical equivalent of this check using the contains forall syntax. i.e. how to construct a `ValueCheck`.

Comment: The argument to foreach in the question is pure, so it should convert nicely. It's just the foreach itself that is making me itch. (I edited the question to remove the red herring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately type inference doesn't work with partial functions so you need to match explicitly:

```
 foo.tails must contain { ts: List[Foo] =>
   ts match {
     case h +: t => h.distanceToEnd.miles must
       beCloseTo(t.map(_.distanceFromPrevious.miles).sum, 10e-10)
     case _ => ok
   }
}.forall
```

Comment: Additionally, I had to declare the body of `contain` as a `val` and give it a type before it would compile, such that the final statement was `foo.tails must contain(sumOfDistancesInTail).forall`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forall` if you calculate the partial sums of `distanceFromPrevious` and subtract `distanceToEnd` before using any specs2 matchers.  Then you can just use one of the [`beCloseTo` matchers](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#out-of-the-box) to compare with 0, as follows:

```
foo.tail.scanRight(0.0)(_.distanceFromPrevious.miles + _).init  // calculate partial sums of previous distances
    .zip(foo.init.map(_.distanceToEnd.miles))                   // combine with end distances
    .map(t => t._1 - t._2)                                      // take difference of summed and end distances
    .must(contain(be ~(0.0 +/- 10e-10)).forall)                 // all differences should be effectively 0
```